# unrecognized jvm option is used and

Tags: android, cordova, hybrid-mobile-app

I am developing android cordova application. I have installed all the setup while am running the app using command prompt am getting below the error.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Unable to start the daemon process.
  This problem might be caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon.
  For example, an unrecognized jvm option is used.
  Please refer to the user guide chapter on the daemon at https://docs.gradle.org
  3.3/userguide/gradle_daemon.html

  ### Please read the following process output to find out more:

Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for 2097152KB object heap

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug

Comment: first guess is you want to assign more heap space ( RAM ) than you have available. I could be wrong though.

Comment: How much size i need to set and were i need to set